# How do I filter a view based on criteria from a secondary blended data source?

Tags: tableau-api

## Upfront:

- Tableau 2018.1.1
- 1st (Primary Datasource) is a data source published to Tableau Server
- 2nd (Secondary Datasource) is a data source published to Tableau Server
- 1st is blended with 2nd based on a date field. There is a many to one relationship.
- 1st has multiple rows per date.
- 2nd has only one row per date.

2nd has a field called 'category' that is blended. There is only one category per date. Every category will have multiple dates associated with it.

## The hard part, AKA why I'm here:

1. For the most recent date that's less than today... (which will be
   the    same in 1st and 2nd dataset)
2. I want the category of that one date
3. I want to filter the data for all dates that have that same category

## What I've accomplished:

I can do part 1, but I can't get part 2 to work to even start on part 3.

Comment: You have fewer restrictions using fields from the primary data source on the filter shelf. Try swapping which data source you are treating as primary.

Comment: Thanks Alex, worth a shot. I'll report back.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore...using your suggestion and a complicated double LOD function, I was able to get the filter to work (achieving parts 1-3!), however I lost the level of detail needed in the primary data source. (I'm getting asterisks)